# Find strings within text in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a string column "word" and a rather large text. Now I want to find those words that appear within that text. So IMHO I need a reverse LIKE operator. Ist that possible in plain SQL (no stored procedures)?

Example: Finding words in rhymes

```
| ID | Word |
| 1  | star |
| 2  | moon |
| 3  | sun  |
| 4  | sky  |
```

Text: Twinkle, twinkle, little star, How I wonder what you are! Up above the world so high, Like a diamond in the sky.

==> should find ID 1: start, 4: sky

Comment: duplicates [Find strings in text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175742/find-strings-in-text) but that question has no SQL answer

Comment: You can reverse the LIKE operator:   WHERE @MyString LIKE '%'+[Word]+'%'

Comment: should be SQL agnostic (in fact I am using Java, querydsl, jpa and currently mysql, which might change later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select ID from tablename
where 'Twinkle, twinkle, little star, How I wonder what you are! Up above the world so high, Like a diamond in the sky.'
LIKE CONCAT('%', word, '%');
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba18b/8)**

Answer (score 1):

The LIKE operator IS reversible.   This is all you need to do:

```
WHERE @MyString LIKE '%'+[Word]+'%'
```

Comment: Your syntax is not MySQL-compliant.

Comment: Ok, I don't know MySQL syntax, but would the principle work in MySQL?